# Continuity of a certain linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

If $L$ is a discontinuous linear operator on a vector space $X$ and $f$ is a continuous linear functional on $X$, can $f(L)$ be a continuous linear functional?

Comment: Sure, we can take $f = 0$.

Comment: Does $f=0$ give the answer?

Answer (score 0):

A nonzero example could be as follows. Let $X=L^2(0,\infty)$ and $Lg=xg,$ with domain $D(L)=\{ g\in X\,:\, xg\in X\}.$ Let $$\varphi(g)=\int\limits_0^1g(x)\,dx$$ Then $$(\varphi\circ L)(g)=  \int\limits_0^1xg(x)\,dx $$